# Can't create subdomain on Route 53 from Another Registrar

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

So here's the situation i bought a domain from a third-party registrar, and moved it to Route 53 by changing the Nameservers on the original registrar to point to AWS.

So far so good, my base domain works normally, however now i'm trying to add a subdomain like

ci.mydomain.com

And for some reason that one doesn't work, do i need to set it up on the original registrar as well? I thought that since the base domain is already being redirected to AWS that it would do the same for all subdomains.
What am i doing wrong here?

The domain is

```
salesonline.pt
```

the Subdomain is

```
ci.salesonline.pt
```

Comment: Give us the actual subdomain and domain so we can take a look.

Comment: @ceejayoz i updated the description with the actual domains

Comment: Works fine here. Both point to `52.55.234.120`. Guessing you've just got a cached NXDOMAIN response that needs time to clear out.

Comment: @ceejayoz yeah it's working now, that was it, thank you for your help :)

Comment: A deligation could take up to 48 hours to complete.